# Passing Jquery value to WordPress function

Tags: functions, jquery

I have a pop up that I would like to display the author information for that particular post.

I am using WordPress Popup Maker and have created a function that I turned into a shortcode so I could use in Popup Maker.

What I want to do is push the ID of a link onclick to a the function that displays the user data.

Here is my Jquery in a hook in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_popup_scripts', 500 );
function my_custom_popup_scripts() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($, document, undefined) {


$('.author-popup').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

});


    // Your custom code goes here.
}(jQuery, document))
</script><?php
}
```

And here is my start of function where I want to control what user data is displayed:

```
function my_author_box() { ?>


<?php


 $args = array(
'author'        =>  "31", //this what I want to change with Jquery 
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

And here is my link to trigger:

```
<a href="#" class="author-popup" id="33">some user</a>
```

I'm not really good with jquery or AJAX which I have read might be a solution. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've to use AJAX for it. You can follow this tutorial https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AJAX for that. What you have to do is:

1. Create a JS script which sends an AJAX request to admin-ajax.php file:

---

```
<script>
 jQuery(".author-popup").on("click", function(){
  var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
  jQuery.post("http://www.yourdomain.com/admin-ajax.php", {action: "my_author_box", id: id}, function(response){
   console.log("Response: " + response);
   //NOTE that 'action' MUST be the same as PHP function name you want to fire
   //you can do whatever you want here with your response
  });
 })
</script>
```

2. Create new file e.x. myajax.php and include it to functions.php
3. Now write a function you want to fire on click, e.x.:

---

```
function my_author_box(){
   $args = array(
    'author' => $_REQUEST['id'];
   );
   query_posts($args);
   die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_author_box', 'my_author_box' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_author_box', 'my_author_box' );
```

That's all. As I said note that `action`has to be the same as PHP function. If you want to have some response from your PHP function just `echo` it and this is what you will get as a response. If you'll get `0` as a response it means that function you want to fire does not exists or you didn't call `die()` at the end of your function. Should work

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, worked perfectly. I even got the '0' error because I didn't call die() so that info helped too. Thanks again